# Cannot upload image in Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, file-upload, laravel-5, laravel-5.1, image-uploading

I make input data with an upload image, my code

```
$name   = $request->input('name');
$images = $request->file('image');
$name_img = $images->getClientOriginalName();
$ext = $images->getClientOriginalExtension();
// Move Uploaded File
$destinationPath = 'img/';
$images->move($destinationPath,$name_img);
$path = $destinationPath.'/'.$name_img;
```

then put them in array, then insert in database

```
$data = array(
'name' => $name,
'image' => $path, );
DB::table('daftar')->insert($data);
return json_encode(array('status' =>true));
```

That code works in Laravel 5.1, but it doesnt work in Laravel 5.2.

Anything wrong with that code for Laravel 5.2?

Thank You. :)

Comment: Why do you have 2 slashes? One in `'img/'` and one in `$path = $destinationPath.'/'.$name_img;`?

Comment: I mean just 'img', without slash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am using this approach and it work:

```
//Use should have use App\Daftar in above your class;
//Your method inputs should be like UploadRequest $request , Daftar $daftar
$file=$request->file('image');
$name=time().'-'.$file->getClientOriginalName();
$path = public_path().'/img';
$file->move($path, $name);


$daftar->create(array('name' => $name, 'image' => $path));
```

Ensure that in the table was not a field that can not be empty

you cal learn more about public_path() here:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/helpers#method-public-path

Also my Upload folder is on public directory

if you want to ensure that data saved in the database is the same as you send check with following approach:

```
//Use should have use App\Daftar in above your class;
//Your method inputs should be like UploadRequest $request , Daftar $daftar
$file=$request->file('image');
$name=time().'-'.$file->getClientOriginalName();
$path = public_path().'/img';
$file->move($path, $name);

print 'name is'.$name.' and image is '.$path;

$daftar->create(array('name' => $name, 'image' => $path));
```

And after that check the data that saved in the database both data should be same.

Comment: If I use this method, I write the code in array like this $data = array(
'file' => $file, ); , is that true ?

Comment: Thank you for your help. The first method you gave me was work, but the path not going to the right path, its going to /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/temp/phpag1cVv. Your first method was   $images=$request->file('image'); $name=time()."-".$images->getClientOriginalName(); $images->move(public_path().'/img',$name);

Comment: where are the path that you save, with this approach i save files in public/Upload

Comment: I save in public/img

Comment: so change path to $path = public_path().'/img';

Comment: Have the other problem, now image goes to public/img, but path name in database is false. this is path name in DB --> /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/temp/phpiSpVxi

Comment: you can print $path; and print $name; and compare with values that save in the database to ensure that those values is correctly save in the database

Comment: Problem solved. Thank you very much, for your help. I appreciate that. :)